# Initialize minesweeper board

Tags: python, minesweeper

I'm running into an issue when initializing a minesweeper board in Python 2.7.  Here is my code so far:

```
class Minesweeper():

def __init__(self, size, num_bombs):

    # Initialize board of zeros
    self.board = [[0]*size]*size
    self.game_over = False
    self.size = size

    self.add_bombs(num_bombs)


def add_bombs(self, num_bombs): 
    # Add bombs
    for i in range(num_bombs):
        row = randint(0, self.size-1)
        column = randint(0, self.size-1)
        self.board[row][column] = 'B'

    print self.board
```

For some reason, my `add_bombs` code is manipulating each sub-array of my board identically, and I have no idea why.

ie. `x = Minesweeper(5,2)` is resulting in:

`[[0, 0, 0, 'B', 'B'], [0, 0, 0, 'B', 'B'], [0, 0, 0, 'B', 'B'], [0, 0, 0, 'B', 'B'], [0, 0, 0, 'B', 'B']]`

Instead of adding 2 total bombs.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the list of empty zeros as this instead:

```
[[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
```

This creates copies of each sublist instead of creating references to the same list.

Comment: That did the trick.  Interesting little quirk there!